# Storing environment variables in a file in a folder on gitlab for GCP functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I want to store environment variables in a file in a folder on gitlab for GCP functions . I can see the documentation for it [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) where I set the argument `--env-vars-file` upon deployment. My folder structure in gitlab looks like the following and I am mirroring this to GCP:

```
-- hello_world.py
-- requirements.txt
-- env_variables
   -- beta.yaml
   -- prod.yaml
```

I deploy this using the command line using the argument as follows: `--env-vars-file env_variables/beta.yaml`. But I get the error:

```
(gcloud) Failed to load YAML from [env_variables/beta.yaml]: Unable to read file [env_variables/beta.yaml]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'env_variable
s/beta.yaml'
```

The file is there though so I am probably referencing it wrongly

Comment: Does it work if the file isn't in the directory? I tested in my side and it works perfectly (with Go runtime). Can you update also your gcloud CLI?

Comment: Hi there!
I have deployed a python function like this [1] and this [2] and was not able to get the error message. 
What is the output of the deployment when you enable the `--log-http` & `verbosity=debug` flags?    
My Cloud SDK version is 327.0.0. What is yours?

Comment: [1]`gcloud functions deploy fc123 --entry-point=hello_method --runtime=python37 --allow-unauthenticated --trigger-http --env-vars-file="env_variables/test.yaml"`

Comment: [2]`gcloud functions deploy fc123 --entry-point=hello_method --runtime=python37 --allow-unauthenticated --trigger-http --env-vars-file env_variables/test.yaml`

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this. So I am mirroring to a gitlab repository. The above is the structure in gitlab. I have updated my question